# Is it possible to use React-Bootstrap and bootstrap.js on the same page?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

We have an existing Bootstrap 3 (Rails) app to which we've been adding React views. We'd now like to use a component that depends on React-Bootstrap. However, since React-Bootstrap has its own [React-based implementation of Bootstrap's JavaScript logic](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html#commonjs), it doesn't want or like `bootstrap.js` being included. If you use both, you get problems like events being handled twice in the React-Bootstrap views. Given that the non-React views depend on `bootstrap.js`, is there any way to get them to co-exist? Some of our React views (particularly modals) are on the same page as non-React Bootstrap components (particularly navs), so we can't just selectively load `bootstrap.js`. React-Bootstrap doesn't interfere with non-React components, and I'm wondering if there's some technique for getting `bootstrap.js` not to interfere with the React ones.